# Unicorn doesn't pick up changes with new deploy of Rails app (Capistrano, Nginx)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, deployment, capistrano, unicorn

I'm new to deploying, so this is probably a rookie mistake, but here it goes.

I have a Rails 4 app that I'm deploying to a Linux server using a combination of Capistrano, Unicorn, and Nginx. The deploy script runs fine and the app is now reachable at the desired IP, so that's great. The thing is, a) Unicorn doesn't restart upon deployment (at least, the PIDs don't change) and b) not surprisingly, the new changes aren't reflected in the available app. I don't seem to be able to do anything other than completely stopping and restarting unicorn in order to refresh it. If I do this, then the changes are picked up, but this process is obviously not ideal.

Manually, if I run `kill -s HUP $UNICORN_PID` then the pids of the workers change but not the master, and changes aren't picked up (which, apparently they are supposed to be); using `USR2` appears to have no effect on the current processes.

Here's the unicorn init script I'm using, based on suggestions from other stack overflow questions with similar problems:

```
set -e

USAGE="Usage: $0 <start|stop|restart|upgrade|rotate|force-stop>"

# app settings
USER="deploy"
APP_NAME="app_name"
APP_ROOT="/path/to/$APP_NAME"
ENV="production"

# environment settings
PATH="/home/$USER/.rbenv/shims:/home/$USER/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
CMD="cd $APP_ROOT/current && bundle exec unicorn -c config/unicorn.rb -E $ENV -D"
PID="$APP_ROOT/shared/pids/unicorn.pid"
OLD_PID="$PID.oldbin"
TIMEOUT=${TIMEOUT-60}

# make sure the app exists
cd $APP_ROOT || exit 1

sig () {
  test -s "$PID" && kill -$1 `cat $PID`
}

oldsig () {
  test -s $OLD_PID && kill -$1 `cat $OLD_PID`
}

case $1 in
  start)
    sig 0 && echo >&2 "Already running" && exit 0
    echo "Starting $APP_NAME"
    su - $USER -c "$CMD"
    ;;
  stop)
    echo "Stopping $APP_NAME"
    sig QUIT && exit 0
    echo >&2 "Not running"
    ;;
  force-stop)
    echo "Force stopping $APP_NAME"
    sig TERM && exit 0
    echo >&2 "Not running"
    ;;
  restart|reload)
    sig HUP && echo "reloaded $APP_NAME" && exit 0
    echo >&2 "Couldn't reload, starting '$CMD' instead"
    run "$CMD"
    ;;
  upgrade)
    if sig USR2 && sleep 2 && sig 0 && oldsig QUIT
    then
      n=$TIMEOUT
      while test -s $OLD_PID && test $n -ge 0
      do
        printf '.' && sleep 1 && n=$(( $n - 1 ))
      done
      echo

    if test $n -lt 0 && test -s $OLD_PID
    then
      echo >&2 "$OLD_PID still exists after $TIMEOUT seconds"
      exit 1
    fi
    exit 0
  fi
  echo >&2 "Couldn't upgrade, starting '$CMD' instead"
  su - $USER -c "$CMD"
  ;;
  rotate)
    sig USR1 && echo rotated logs OK && exit 0
    echo >&2 "Couldn't rotate logs" && exit 1
    ;;
  *)
    echo >&2 $USAGE
    exit 1
    ;;
esac
```

Using this script, `start` and `stop` work as expected, but `reload`/`restart` do nothing (they print the expected output but don't change the running pids) and `upgrade` fails. According to the error log, it's because the first master is still running (`ArgumentError: Already running on PID: $PID`).

And here's my unicorn.rb:

```
app_path = File.expand_path("../..", __FILE__)
working_directory "#{app_path}"
pid               "#{app_path}/../../shared/pids/unicorn.pid"

# listen
listen "#{app_path}/../../shared/sockets/unicorn.sock", :backlog => 64

# logging
stderr_path "#{app_path}/../../shared/log/unicorn.stderr.log"
stdout_path "#{app_path}/../../shared/log/unicorn.stdout.log"

# workers
worker_processes 3

# use correct Gemfile on restarts
before_exec do |server|
  ENV['BUNDLE_GEMFILE'] = "#{working_directory}/Gemfile"
end

# preload
preload_app false

before_fork do |server, worker|
  old_pid = "#{app_path}/shared/pids/unicorn.pid.oldbin"
  if File.exists?(old_pid) && server.pid != old_pid
    begin
      Process.kill("QUIT", File.read(old_pid).to_i)
    rescue Errno::ENOENT, Errno::ESRCH
      # someone else did our job for us
    end
  end
end

after_fork do |server, worker|
  if defined?(ActiveRecord::Base)
    ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection
  end
end
```

Any help is very much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is hard to say for certain, since I haven't encountered this particular issue before, but my hunch is that this is your problem:

```
app_path = File.expand_path("../..", __FILE__)
working_directory "#{app_path}"
```

Every time you deploy, Capistrano creates a new directory for your app at the location `releases/<timestamp>`. It then updates a `current` symlink to point at this latest release directory.

In your case, you may mistakenly be telling Unicorn to use `releases/<timestamp>` as its `working_directory`. (SSH to the server and check the contents of `unicorn.rb` to be certain.) Instead, what you should do is point to `current`. That way you don't have to stop and cold start unicorn to get it to see the new working directory.

```
# Since "current" is a symlink to the current release,
# Unicorn will always see the latest code.
working_directory "/var/www/my-app/current"
```

I suggest rewriting your unicorn.rb so that you aren't using relative paths. Instead hard-code the absolute paths to `current` and `shared`. It is OK to do this because those paths will remain the same for every release.

Comment: Yup, can't believe I missed that! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
ENV="production"
```

looks extremely suspicious to me. I suspect that it wants to be

```
RAILS_ENV="production".
```

without this won't rails wake up not knowing which environment it is?